# React не работает в браузере

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Начал изучать React и столкнулся с первой проблемой. Создал HTML-разметку и в теге script написал программу "Hello World", но запись не отображается на странице.

Вот сам код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Созданное приложение будет находиться здесь -->
    <div id="app">
        <!-- Smth -->
    </div>

    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
    <script>
        ReactDom.render(
            React.Dom.h1(null, "Hello World!"),
            document.getElementById("app")
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Файлы "react.js" "react-dom.js" и "hello.html" на одном уровне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если прям хочется запустить react в таком варианте то если немного поправить код то добиться чтоб он заработал можно, я брал react библиотеки из cdn.Перенес загрузку скриптов в `<head>`,

И вместо

```
React.Dom.h1(null, "Hello World!"),
```

написал так

```
React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World"),
```

В результате код приобрел следующий вид, и работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Созданное приложение будет находиться здесь -->
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World"),
        document.getElementById("app")
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Но вообще для изучения react. Есть готовый инструмент create-react-app.

Изучите как он устанавливается,и работает, используя webpack.И это будет наиболее правильный путь изучения react